# JTable with titled rows and columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I have a JTable with both columns & rows have title?
something like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|/\/\/\| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| row1 |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+
| row2 |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+
| row3 |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? I suggest you read the following tutorial: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that you searching RowTable

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JTableRowHeader {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable RowHeader");
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    private JTable headerTable;

    public JTableRowHeader() {
        table = new JTable(4, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            table.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
        }
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return table.getRowCount();
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
                switch (colNum) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return super.getColumnClass(colNum);
                }
            }
        };
        headerTable = new JTable(model);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            headerTable.setValueAt("Row " + (i + 1), i, 0);
        }
        headerTable.setShowGrid(false);
        headerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(50, 0));
        headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                boolean selected = table.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
                Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                if (selected) {
                    component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                    component.setForeground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                }
                return component;
            }
        });
        table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {

            @Override
            public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                model.fireTableDataChanged();
            }
        });
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() - 1);
            }
        });
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(headerTable);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Object>() {

                @Override
                public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
                    return ((Number) entry.getValue(0)).intValue() % 2 == 0;
                }
            };

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {// UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTableRowHeader TestTableRowHeader = new JTableRowHeader();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but my code is pre-school compare with @camickrs http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/

Comment: Nice. I figured this question would be up your alley.

Comment: Can header display Row 1 and Row 3 instead of Row 1 and Row 2 ?

Comment: @Ron Ron yes because there is harcoded `return ((Number) entry.getValue(0)).intValue() % 2 == 0;` inside `public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {`, code in SSCCE / MCVE form

Comment: I proposed a version below to display corresponding row header after filtering (hardcoded and dynamic data).

Answer (score 0):

Row header and table value are desynchronized in solution from mKorbel. The table displays Row 1 and Row 2 instead of Row 1 and Row 3 when filtered.

Here is a solution based on his example. It duplicates row header into a new column in the table, hide this column and copy values to the other one when filtered.

It works and it's ugly, we need a better solution from someone :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class JTableRowHeader {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable RowHeader");
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    private JTable headerTable;

    public JTableRowHeader() {
        table = new JTable(4, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            table.setValueAt("Row " + (i + 1), i, 0);
            table.setValueAt(i, i, 1);
        }
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return table.getRowCount();
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
                switch (colNum) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return super.getColumnClass(colNum);
                }
            }
        };
        headerTable = new JTable(model);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            headerTable.setValueAt("Row " + (i + 1), i, 0);
        }
        headerTable.setShowGrid(false);
        headerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(50, 0));
        headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                boolean selected = table.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
                Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                if (selected) {
                    component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                    component.setForeground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                }
                return component;
            }
        });
        table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {

            @Override
            public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                model.fireTableDataChanged();
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    headerTable.setValueAt(table.getValueAt(i, 0), i, 0);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() - 1);
            }
        });

        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(0);
        column.setMinWidth(0);
        column.setMaxWidth(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(0);

        AdjusterTableColumn columnAdjuster = new AdjusterTableColumn(table);
        columnAdjuster.adjustColumns();

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(headerTable);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Object>() {

                @Override
                public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
                    return ((Number) entry.getValue(1)).intValue() % 2 == 0;
                }
            };

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {// UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTableRowHeader TestTableRowHeader = new JTableRowHeader();
            }
        });
    }
}
```