# Swing JTable customization for filtering/searching

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, renderer

I'd like to add filtering/searching capability for all columns (so that it is generic) the logic is not a problem.  However, I was thinking is that the best way to do that in terms of visualization is having a text field above each column header (or part of the column header)?

I've run into a couple of problems when trying to achieve that:

1. Embedding within the column header demands implementing a new renderer + there's the problem that somehow I need to catch the event because the cell is drawn and does not respond to events.  Looks like an overkill to me.
2. Having a separate line (panel) of text field components above each column sounds much easier at first glance, however, aligning the text field with the columns is problematic since I didn't find an API in `JTable` or `TableColumn` that returns the coordinates of the column.  Moreover, moving the column around would mean adjusting the text fields as well (which is possible but another overhead).

Am I missing something or it is indeed that hard to achieve something as simple as that? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There is a library for your first approach. It can easily be integrated and works really great: [Swing Bits](http://github.com/eugener/oxbow)

Answer (score 2):

```
of visualization is having a textfield above each column header 
(or part of the column header)...
```

- you have look at [RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html), simple [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187799/714968)
- use [AutoComplete JComboBox & JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968) for seaching

Answer (score 0):

See hereunder an sample for Filtering rely on text field entries filtering your Jtable data
rely on text box entry :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
```

public class TestTableSorterFilter extends JApplet {

```
private String[] columnNames
        = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

private Object[][] data = {
    {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
    {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
    {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
    {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
    {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
    {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
    {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
};

private JTable jTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
        = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable.getModel());

private JTextField jtfFilter = new JTextField();
private JButton jbtFilter = new JButton("Filter");

public TestTableSorterFilter() {
    jTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("Specify a word to match:"),
            BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(jtfFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(new JScrollPane(jTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jtfFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();

            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
            }   
        }
    });
}
}
```