# JTable Row Header Text

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Can somebody show me if there is a way to add a row header with a text, or maybe there is some type of trick, which will allow us to do something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RowHeader is

- [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187799/714968)
- [better way](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/)