# Is it possible to add Row headers to a JSF or PrimeFaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, datatable, rowheader

Well, I've been looking for any examples but all I could find was just examples in plain Java but I need to do something like [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TableRowHeaderExample.htm) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170969/creating-row-headers-for-jtable-at-run-time) but in a JSF or PrimeFaces component.

Comment: This isn't either, thx for your reply but it was of no help

Comment: You can define style of 1st column exact the same as table header.

Comment: In 1st column cell add subTable and fill only header, rest of row cells leave as is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `h:column` tag has a property called `rowHeader` that does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<f:facet name="header">
  Row Header Example
</f:facet>
```

Here is the complete example:
Primefaces showcase - DataTable - Group [1](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml)

I think you want something like a horizontal header, a don't think primefaces has it, but you can change the style of first cell like this:

```
<p:column headerText="Id"> 
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" styleClass="someCssClass" /> 
</p:column>
```

Comment: Thx for your quick reply but it isn't what im looking for, why dont you check the examples on my question above?

Comment: What's wrong with what @Claudinei posted? It does exactly what you need: an header. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As I said i need a row header not a column one.

Comment: I think there are no row headers. Headers are always on top of something, so the solution @Claudinei suggested is exactly identical to the pictures you provided. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex I think you want some like a horizontal header, a don't think primefaces has it, but you can change the style of first cell.