# Filtering a Table using a Combobox in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have got a table and four combo-boxes namely "Asset Categories","Department:","Branches:" and "Asset State".

problem: Now i want to be able to filter my table in such a way that i can select a category of an asset "LAND & BUILDING" and will want to select the branch of the asset.

so when i select "LAND & BUILDING" it shows in my table and when i select a branch, it also appears in the table. so the output in the table becomes

```
 ASSET CATEGORY   |   BRANCHES
------------------|-------------
LAND & BUILDING   |   BRANCH 1
```

and so on for the other combo-boxes. I would really appreciate the help thanks

Comment: You would do this the exact same way in Netbeans 7 as in Netbeans 6, Eclipse or a Java file written using a text editor.  In other words, Netbeans has nothing to do with it and is an irrelevant tag.

Comment: *"I would really appreciate the help"*  Do you have a question?  Have you tried anything?  For example, Google for 'JTable filter tutorial' shows top link as [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which seems to cover the exact requirement.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and pay attention to the [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section

Comment: @Sarkwa sorry don't understand, I miss question, direction, sence

Answer (score 2):

Table sorting and filtering is managed by a sorter object. The easiest way to provide a sorter object is to set `autoCreateRowSorter` bound property to true:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

And then, you can use [`RowFilter.regexFilter(String regex, int... indices)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29) with the sorter.
Pleas look into the section [Sorting and Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section of the official tutorial page which contains example. You can use `ItemListener` with the `JComboBox` to  create new filter to work with using the `regexFiler` function on item selection event.

```
jComboBox2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

   @Override
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

     JComboBox comb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
     String selText = (String) comb.getSelectedItem();
     RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rf = null;

     try {
         rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(selText,
                                 table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("ASSET CATEGORY"));
      } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      ((TableRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(rf);

     }
});
```

Comment: [it should be little bit complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8187799/714968), [but](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854854/jtable-rowfilter-and-rowfilter-entry) +1 for direction....

Comment: @mKorbel, i see. Yes identity less header will have issue :) +1 to your linked work.