# Disable JTable rowsorter for HeaderView

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter, rowsorter

I am having 2 `JTables`, one for displaying the rows and one for displaying the data:

[image]

Problem: When the data table are sorted, also the rows are sorted:

[image]

Is it possible to make the "RowHeaderView" table to not get sorted like the data table?

```
public class SimpleJTableHeader extends JFrame {

    public JTable table;

    public SimpleJTableHeader() {

        // CREATE A JTABLE
        Object rowData[][] = { { "a" }, { "b" }, { "c" }, { "d" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "1" };
        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // ADD ROW NUMBERS TO THE TABLE
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(getHeaderTable());

        // SHOW TABLE
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTable getHeaderTable() {
        final AbstractTableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return table.getRowCount();
            }
        };
        JTable headerTable = new JTable(model);
        headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(40, 0));
        headerTable.setRowHeight(20);
        return headerTable;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SimpleJTableHeader();
    }
}
```

Comment: _don't_ convert the rowIndex in getValueAt of header's model

Comment: return `row` in table model instead of converted value.

Comment: remove [RowSorter's sync betweens two JTables (RowSorterListener)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8187799/714968), to test the better workaround for RowHeader in comments

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to mKorbel the new correct getHeaderTable method:

```
public JTable getHeaderTable() {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return table.getRowCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return super.getColumnClass(colNum);
            }
        }
    };

    JTable headerTable = new JTable(model);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        headerTable.setValueAt((i + 1), i, 0);
    }
    headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(40, 0));
    headerTable.setRowHeight(20);
    return headerTable;
}
```

Comment: you can to use Jlist instead of 2nd. JTable used for RowHeader, limitations is that isn't editable (can be unwanted, I want that this Object should be to editable)

Comment: ehh ... that's far too complicated (besides being unsafe and not really sync'ed to the main table as @mKorbel's example is): simply extend AbstractTableModel (to make it safe against modifications) and return _row_ (or _row +1_, just as you like) from the getter

Comment: @kleopatra good point for safe_mode_solution, but I think this answer can't be down_voted

Comment: @kleopatra I think this is what I tried to do in my question example but did not succeed?

Comment: you returned the _converted_ row index