# "this" is not recognized - Java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, this

I'm trying to use that code https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187799 but with one change: I'm extending my class to JTable so that I can do whatever I want with it when I'm done. Then, I simply just have to replace the occurences of `table` by `this`. But in this part of the code, it doesn't work because I'm overriding some method:

```
 headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            boolean selected = getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
            Component component = getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(*this*, value, false, false, -1, -2);
            ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            if (selected) {
                component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                component.setForeground(Color.red);
            } else {
                component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
            }
            return component;   
        }
    });
```

How can I use `this` as I intend to? (The `this` that is causing me troubles is between `*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The this you are using refers to TableCellRenderer.

You have to use

```
TopLevelClassName.this
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes (didn't know that there was a delay to accept answers).